# Find a word in HTML document and Assign ID/Class to that element

Tags: javascript, html, regex, indexof

I am looking for a way to find a word and based on that word determine what element it's in for the purpose of styling that element. I have to search through a report that is auto-generated, elements and the reports generated are just very long lists of span tags as shortened in the below code. The report is never the same length.

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered)">
</head>

<body lang=EN-US>

<div class=WordSection1>

<p class=MsoPlainText><span style='font-family:"Courier New"'>&nbsp;</span></p>

<p class=MsoPlainText><span style='font-family:"Courier New"'>Filters</span></p>

<p class=MsoPlainText><span style='font-family:"Courier New"'>                                   
Filter Name: BADDATAFILTER                                        </span></p>

<p class=MsoPlainText><span style='font-family:"Courier New"'>&nbsp;</span></p>

<p class=MsoPlainText><span style='font-family:"Courier New"'>Description</span></p>

<p class=MsoPlainText><span style='font-family:"Courier New"'>                                   
Record Type: A                                              </span></p>

<p class=MsoPlainText><span style='font-family:"Courier New"'>                                   
Description: SKIP BAD INFO                                  </span></p>

<p class=MsoPlainText><span style='font-family:"Courier New"'>&nbsp;</span></p>

<p class=MsoPlainText><span style='font-family:"Courier New"'>Conditions</span></p>

<p class=MsoPlainText><span style='font-family:"Courier New"'>                    
Condition Argument: 1 Or 2 Or 3 Or 4 Or 5 Or 6 Or 7 Or 8 Or 9 Or 10 Or 11   </span></p>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I have played around with RegExp which I'm not sure can really help me. I checked out indexOf(), which I think is a solution but I'm not quite sure how I can do this right this moment. Does anybody have an idea?

This is where I was trying to go with it, but this code is bad code. Just posting so you can have an idea of what I'm trying or see where I'm trying to go with this.

```
for each (i in document.body) {
  if (spans[i].text.indexOf('SKIP BAD INFO') != -1) {
console.log("string found");
//do more stuff, like get the element we found the word in to style it.
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "search( )" method to search a string for a specified value. 
It will return -1 if there's no match.

```js
//Search for 'SKIP BAD INFO'
var search = document.querySelectorAll('span');
var resultIndex = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < search.length; i++){
  if(search[i].innerText.search('SKIP BAD INFO') != -1){
    console.log('text found!');
    resultIndex = i;
  }
}

//Assign ID/Class
search[resultIndex].classList.add('className'); //Class
search[resultIndex].setAttribute('id', 'idName'); //ID

//Change CSS
search[resultIndex].style.color = red;
```

If there is more than one result, store indexes in array.

```
resultIndex = [];

//In the for loop
resultIndex.push(i);
```